# How to migrate from heroku to Amazon Web Services while using parse server

Tags: amazon-web-services, heroku, amazon-ec2, parse-server, mlab

I am developing an android app and was using parse.com until they shut down. I had successfully migrated from parse to Heroku but I'm now considering migrating from Heroku to AWS (due to pricing and scalability concerns). I have searched everywhere in the internet but haven't found a site that gives you the step by step instructions on how to do so. I have seen that both Heroku and AWS use mlab as a database so it can't be that hard. Detailed help will really be appreciated as I am still new to programming. Here is what I have attempted in Elastic Beanstalk:

[image: This is the heroku folder where my parse server was located]

[image: This is how I compressed it]

[image: I then went to my app on elastic beanstalk and created a new environment]

[image: I uploaded my zipped file]

[image: It then started creating the environment]

[image]

[image: By the time it was done, it said the status was degraded]

When I was done creating the environment It said that the health was degraded, even after I copied the server variables from parse and added them to the configuration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have your server codes which u published onto Heroku? If i guessed correctly, you are using the [parse-server-master](https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server-example) template for your server right?

In that case, migration is easy. Just zip up the contents and go over to AWS Elastic Beanstalk and upload your zip. It will work ;)

Comment: Zip up what contents? The database?

Comment: your parse server. the one with the index.html, your cloud codes, everything.

Comment: I managed to upload parse server to elastic beanstalk but it says that health is degraded due to 'impaired services on all instances.' I have connected it to the mongodb I was using in heroku. So far the app isn't connecting to the parse server. Is there any crucial step I've missed? If you could give me details on how to do the migration, that would be great.

Comment: Make sure you zip it up your server as follows: [link](https://puu.sh/vrgR4/7046f37978.png) this way, your server should be status ok instead of impaired services.

Comment: If you could provide screenshots of the steps you did, I could correct the mistakes you did and help you better.

Comment: No wonder you couldnt get it to work! Open up cmd and navigate to the server folder, Enter the command:

npm install

re-zip your server and try uploading again :)

Comment: Now it won't compress. I think the file names of the node modules are too long.

Comment: Move your server file to the desktop and try again. I just saw the filepath is in programs 86 no wonder it's too long.

Comment: Well, it worked! Now the environment health is OK. I have set up the server variables and set the DATABASE_URI to the mongodb uri I was using in heroku. When I try to run the application on the android phone I get the error i/o failure. Perhaps I've missed another step?

Comment: Are you sure you are pointing to the new AWS server uri on ur app? In the AWS Elastic beanstalk settings under security, make sure to allow connections (HTTPS/HTTP/SSH) as inbound connections(for testing purposes now). If possible provide me more details.

Comment: Well now it works completely turns out I had been using the old heroku URI. Thanks for your help.